# Access Db `Long Text` Unicode Byte Corruption

Tags: ms-access

I have a column that is `Long Text` when I attempt to edit a cell it randomly inserts characters and does other weird things. The column has French `HTML` text in it. What could be causing this and what could fix it? I assume there might be a `byte` offset problem but I never dealt with that before. I've googled around and haven't been able to find anything on it.

E.g.,

```
<li>Se présente en nappes.</li>
```

When I type a `space`, , right after the first word `Se` it inserts an `e`, e.g.,

```
<li>Se e présente en nappes.</li>
```

I don't work with `Access` very much so this is quite strange to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a `\n` character that was imported into the record. Did a query on the data and removed it and updated the record. Not having issues anymore.